# Python create object depending on a variable name

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am trying to create a Fruit object but I don't know exactly which fruit to create.

I have a dictionary that loaded all the classes into a dictionary.

```
fruits = {'Apple': <module 'Apple' from '.'>, 'Orange': <module 'Orange' from '.', 'Banana': <module 'Banana' from '.'>
```

I then have a variable that contains the fruit name I want to create. So I can set this to Apple, Orange, or Banana.

```
myfruit = 'Orange'
```

I also have some simple classes.

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Orange:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Banana:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

I want to basically create a object based on whatever myfruit variable is set to.

```
fruit_obj = myfruit()
```

My end game is to be able to create a large amount of classes for various things, and then whenever myfruit is set, it creates a object of that type.

EDIT:
This is what I am doing to load the key (filename) to module.

```
def load_up(path):
    COMMAND_FOLDER = path + '/'
    commands = [f for f in listdir(COMMAND_FOLDER) if isfile(join(COMMAND_FOLDER, f)) and f[-3:] == '.py']
    commands_map = {}
    for command in commands:
        name = command[:-3]
        path = COMMAND_FOLDER + command
        spec = spec_from_file_location(name, path)
        foo = module_from_spec(spec)
        spec.loader.exec_module(foo)

        commands_map[name] = foo

    return commands_map
```

Comment: Map it differently: `{'Apple': Apple, 'Orange': Orange}`

Comment: Does `fruit_obj = fruits[myfruit]()` work for you?

Comment: @OlivierMelançon I get TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following the import of the various classs, you could do like this, with a dictionary to map the `fruit_name` to the `class` to be created

```
from module import Orange, Apple, Banana


fruits = {'Apple': Apple, 'Orange': Orange, 'Banana': Banana}

myfruit = 'Orange'
fruit_obj = fruits[myfruit]()   # -> creates an object of type Orange
```

With the following classes in `module.py`:

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Orange:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Banana:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```